# Delete specific table in Database using php

Tags: php, mysql, delete-row

I need to delete a specific table on database using PHP code. The problem is that everytime I click "delete", the whole table is deleted.

Here is my code for `delete.php`:

```
<?php
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","neust");
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }

 mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM announcement WHERE id=id");

 mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
 <script>alert("Deleted");document.location="Announcement.php"</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm assuming you want to delete a specific row. You need to change `id=id` to something like `id=$id` where $id is a variable containing an integer of the row you want deleted.

For instance, if you wanted to delete the row that has the id 4 you would do

```
mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM announcement WHERE id=4");
```

Comment: yes but when i click delete. i can only delete the link where id=4. what i like is if i delete a specific table it would automaticaly be the value for id.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM announcement WHERE id=id");
```

shouldn't it be $id or something ? id=id is true for all records in the table!

Comment: im working a admin panel of my website. its where i could delete a specific entry for feedbacks.what i would like it to be is to auto increment the value of id for the table i will delete.

Comment: so you basically have a table for every feedback ?

Comment: yes. i call for every result using $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * from announcement order by id desc limit 15");
?>
<table width="500px" style="border:2px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;" id="table">
<tr>

<td width="15%" style="border:2px solid black;color:Black"><b><center>Announcements</center></b></td>
</tr>

<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
   
   ?><tr>
<td width="500px" style="border:1px solid black;color:white"><?php echo $row['Announcement']    ?></td>

</tr>

Comment: yes I think the statement should be

mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM announcement WHERE id=$id");